# Is it wrong to cast an enumerator of a child class to an enumerator of a parent class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance

I've got an error in my build which says:

> Error 12  Cannot implicitly convert
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator< BaseClass>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator< IParentClass>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Is it wrong to simply cast it away?

This is my code:

```
public Dictionary<Int32, BaseClass> Map { get; private set; }

public IEnumerator<BaseClass> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Map.Values.GetEnumerator();
        }

public IEnumerator<IParentClass> IEnumerable<IParentClass>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator(); // ERROR!
        }
```

My question is, can I just change this line:

```
return this.GetEnumerator();
```

to:

```
return (IEnumerator<IParentClass>)this.GetEnumerator();
```

(without any bad side effects)?

**Accepted Answer:**
I've changed the function to the following (after reading Jon Skeet's post):

```
IEnumerator<IParentClass> IEnumerable<IParentClass>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Map.Values.Cast<IParentClass>().GetEnumerator();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, because generics aren't covariant in C# at the moment. .NET itself has some support (for delegates and interfaces) but it's not really used yet.

If you were returning `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` instead of `IEnumerator<BaseClass>` (and assuming .NEt 3.5) you could use `Enumerable.Cast` - but you'll currently need to write your own extension method, e.g.

```
public static IEnumerator<TParent> Upcast<TParent, TChild>
    (this IEnumerator<TChild> source)
    where TChild : TParent
{
    while (source.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return source.Current;
    }
}
```

Alternatively in your case you could use Cast earlier:

```
return this.Map.Values.Cast<BaseClass>().GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, at least in C# 3.0 and below interface variance is not supported. See Eric Lippert's excellent series on this, and specifically [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerator<BaseClass>` and `IEnumerator<ParentClass>` are unrelated, eventhough their generic parameters are.  I would instead use a LINQ `Select` extension method like so:

```
return this.Select(x => (IParentClass)x).GetEnumerator();
```

or the `Cast` extension method:

```
return this.Cast<IParentClass>().GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: No can do with IEnumerator - you need IEnumerable. (In which case just use Cast() in the first place :)

Comment: I've corrected the example.  I also included the Cast() method.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't safe, see below:

using System.Collections.Generic;
class Foo { }
class Bar : Foo { }

```
static class Program
{
    static IEnumerator<Foo> GetBase() {
        yield return new Foo();
        yield return new Bar();
    }
    static IEnumerator<Bar> GetDerived()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<Bar>)GetBase();
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = GetDerived(); // EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

However, you should be able to use an iterator block to do the cast for you?

```
static IEnumerator<Bar> GetDerived()
{
    using (IEnumerator<Foo> e = GetBase())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            // or use "as" and only return valid data
            yield return (Bar)e.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reason *why* this isn't appropriate, picture instead of an `Enumerator`, a `List`.  Both use generics - the compiler doesn't handle either one in a special way in relation to generic arguments.

```
void doStuff() {
    List<IParentThing> list = getList();
    list.add(new ChildThing2());
}

List<IParentThing> getList() {
    return new List<ChildThing1>();  //ERROR!
}
```

This first method is fine - a list of `IParentThing`s should be able to recieve a `ChildThing2`.  But a list of `ChildThing1`s cannot handle a `ChildThing2`, or indeed any implementor of `IParentThing` other than `ChildThing1` - in other words, if the `List&lt;ChildThing1>` was allowed to cast as a `List&lt;IParent>`, it would have to be able to deal with *all* subclasses of `IParentThing`, not just `IParentThing` and `ChildThing1`.

Note that Java generics have a way to say that "I want a list of anything that inherits from this" in addition to "I want a list of anything that this inherits," which allows for more interesting (and in my opinion elegant) solutions to some problems.