# Passing interface as a parameter to an extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, interface

I have used extension methods to extend html helpers to make an RSS repeater:

```
    public static string RSSRepeater(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<IRSSable> rss)
    {
        string result="";

        foreach (IRSSable item in rss)
        {
            result += "<item>" + item.GetRSSItem().InnerXml + "</item>";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So I make one of my business objects implement IRSSable, and try to pass this to the HTML helper. But I just cannot seem to make it work, I have tried:

```
<%=Html.RSSRepeater(ViewData.Model.GetIssues(null, null, "") as IEnumerable<IRSSable>) %>
```

Compiles fine, but null is passed

```
<%=Html.RSSRepeater(ViewData.Model.GetIssues(null, null, "")) %>
```

Intellisense moans about not being able to pass IEnumerable issue to IEnumberable IRSSable

- So how do you do it? That method I am calling definitly returns `IEnumberable<Issue>` and Issue definitly implements IRSSAble

Comment: Without seeing what the GetIssues method is doing it is very hard to say with any certainty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ahh... try:

```
 public static string RSSRepeater<T>(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> rss)
     where T : IRSSable
 {
     ...
 }
```

This then should allow you to pass any sequence of things that implement `IRSSable` - and the generic type inference should mean you don't need to specify the `T` (as `Issue`) yourself - the compiler will handle it.

By the way - [avoid concatenation here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html); `StringBuilder` is preferable:

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (IRSSable item in rss)
    {
        result.Append("<item>").Append(item.GetRSSItem().InnerXml).Append("</item>");
    }

    return result.ToString();
```

Comment: Nice - like it. Trust you to take a step back and approach it from a better direction :)

Comment: Excellent! This allows me to keep it nice and elegant. If i could vote  you twice, I would

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Marc, I never knew that. There is clearly a reason you have 11k points :p

Answer (score 4):

You're running into [generic variance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229656). Just because something implements `IEnumerable<Issue>` doesn't mean it implements `IEnumerable<IRssable>`. (It will in C# 4, but I'm assuming you're not using that :)

You could make your extension method take just `IEnumerable` and call `IEnumerable.Cast<IRssable>` on it though - that's probably the simplest approach.

EDIT: [Marc's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325561/passing-interface-as-a-parameter-to-an-extension-method#325568) is probably the better one, but I'll leave this answer here as it explains what's going on rather than just the fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%=Html.RSSRepeater(ViewData.Model.GetIssues(null, null, "").Cast<IRSSable>()) %>
```