# PHP: Passing Interface as Parameter

Tags: php, oop, interface

In .NET I have done that I passed Interfaces as parameters in class methods. I want to know is it possible in PHP?

My scnerio is that I have a class dealing with mqin system functionality. Now I want to integrate Notification system with it. I want to keep notification system separate since it is not the main part of the system plus I can use it somewhere else. If I have the following structure:

```
Interface INotification
{
  public set()
  public send()
}
```

And then I do:

```
class MyClass
{
   public setNotifier(INotification $notifier)
  {
  }
}
```

So Is it possible that I can access set() and send() here after implementing them in a class? I want to know how [this C# Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325561/passing-interface-as-a-parameter-to-an-extension-method) work that they set parameters of an Interface type.

Thanks

Comment: You only forgot the `function` keyword everywhere and semicolons in the interface declaration. But that's how it works.

Comment: This counts for most parts of php: just do it. Just call the method on your parameter, it will work.

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, pretty much as you wrote. Example of such interface: http://api.nette.org/2.0/source-Http.IResponse.php.html#18 and example of such parameter: http://api.nette.org/2.0/source-Http.Context.php.html#32

Comment: Awesome. A pretty much clear explaination how OOPS complex feature gonna work. Infact other things are also well explained. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What advantage do I get passing Interface as parameters instead of object of type Class? see the code. http://pastebin.ca/2088573

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do as you coded. You can find [more information and examples on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

Note that specifying the type in the method parameter ([type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)) is allowed (PHP >= 5), but not required.