# Why interface in action not finding model?

Tags: php, laravel

Why isn't this working? When I use Interface in action, it doesn't find the model by id. But when I use a certain class, it doesn't matter.

```
interface MyModelInterface
{
    //
}

class MyModel extends Model implements MyModelInterface
{
    //
}

class MyService extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(MyModelInterface::class, MyModel::class);
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function info(MyModelInterface $model)
    {
        return view('info', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}

Route::get('/info/{model}', 'MyController@info')->name('info');

<a href="{{route('info', ['model' => 6])}}">Link</a>
```

The `$model` in the 'info' action will be empty, like `$model = new MyModel;`

When I don't use the interface, it works:

```
public function info(MyModel $model)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Passing Interface as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705348/php-passing-interface-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
interface MyModelInterface extends \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable
{
    //...
}
```

Thanks!